# Separate form for $f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

> $\qquad^{\star\star}(b)$ Prove, more generally, that
>   $$f'(x) = \lim_{h, k \to 0^+}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x - k)}{h + k}$$

**ONLY HINTS PLEASE.**

The denominator is the issue. I thought of $u = h + k$ but that created an issue  for the limit bounds. I tried adding and subtraction $f(x)$ in the numerator but the denominator causes issues.

**ONLY HINTS PLEASE!**

Attempts:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h, k \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x + h + k) + f(x + h + k) - f(x - k)}{h+k} $$

$$ = \lim_{h, k \to 0} -\frac{f(x + h + k) - f(x + h)}{h+k} + \frac{f(x + h + k) - f(x - k)}{h+k}$$

let $u = x + k$. As $k , h\to 0,$ $u \to x$ and $x - k =  u - 2k$

Which makes things weird.

Comment: I’m inclined to give a full answer, just to counter the boldface capslock.

Comment: 1.) Do you already know the result for “$k=h$”, and 2.) do you know the mean value theorem?

Comment: @k.stm, MVT is not suposed to be used. Please do not give a full answer... Thanks

Comment: Nah, don’t worry. I wouldn’t be able to give a full answer without the use of the mean value theorem anyway (as of now, at least). But, please update your question to put in more info (like the answers to my questions above) and maybe remove at least one of the boldface capslocks (I find it a bit disturbing – this may only be me, though). You should also clearly state what $f$ is and which nice properties it has.

Comment: My hint: Taylor's theorem.  Use a version that works even when the derivative exists at only one point.

Comment: @GEdgar, as much asI would like to use that, it is NOT allowed. This problem was in the beginning fo the chapter: "derivatives," we dont even know about chain rule et... yet/...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the evaluation of $f'(x-k)$ and $h'=k+h$.